# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.openDrawer')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to Create a Global Header that can call the Navigation Drawer

My main code is like this :

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList,DrawerItem, } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
    import Header from './components/Headertest';
    
    function Screen1() {
      return (
        <View>    
        <View><Text>Screen1</Text></View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    function Screen2() {
      return (
        <View>    
        <View><Text>Screen2</Text></View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
    function MyDrawer() {
      return (
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    }
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Header />
          <MyDrawer />      
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

And my Header Code is like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

class Header extends React.Component {
  
  render() {    
    return(     
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height:50, backgroundColor:'#12415e', marginTop: 25 }}>    
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems:'center',flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Icon style= {{color: 'white'}} name='bars'/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>                
    </View>    
  )
  }  
}

export default Header;
```

But instead an error appears like this:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.openDrawer')

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Depends on what `this.props.navigation.openDrawer` does. If it tries to get `this` binding it will get `undefined`, which seems to be the problem. Does changing it to `() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` help?

Comment: I have updated the code that I created, but it looks like the error is still the same

Comment: You forgot to add parentheses after `openDrawer`. It should be `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}`

Comment: I updated the code by adding a parenthesis after openDrawer, but the error is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Header />` component is not inside a `Navigator`, so it doesn't have access to the `navigation` props. Make the `<Header />` component a functional component and use the `useNavigation()` hook.

More details here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop